# Different behavior when space is encoded as + and %20 in a URL

Tags: java, url, encoding, query-string

Pages with spaces in the URL don't get correctly translated:
i.e.

http://www.streetinsider.com/Press Releases/National Trends Reflected in Plano Housing Market/9778767.html

or

http://www.streetinsider.com/Press%20Releases/National+Trends+Reflected+in+Plano+Housing+Market/9778767.html

Gives 404. Please note "Press Releases" is encoded as "Press%20Releases".

However following two versions work fine where "Press Releases" is encoded as "Press+Releases".

http://www.streetinsider.com/Press+Releases/National+Trends+Reflected+in+Plano+Housing+Market/9778767.html

The article parses fine with plus signs or HEX spaces %20.
http://www.streetinsider.com/Press+Releases/National%20Trends%20Reflected%20in%20Plano%20Housing%20Market/9778767.html

Both + and %20 represent spaces. Then why this behavior.

And also, in java what could I use to get the correct encoded URL

Answer (score 1):

> Both + and %20 represent spaces

Only in query strings.  Elsewhere in a URL a plus is a plus, not a space.  In this case the web server gives you the same *content* for the two different *URLs*

> http://www.streetinsider.com/Press+Releases/National+Trends+Reflected+in+Plano+Housing+Market/9778767.html

and

> http://www.streetinsider.com/Press+Releases/National%20Trends%20Reflected%20in%20Plano%20Housing%20Market/9778767.html

but the two URLs are distinct, they're not alternative representations of the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

Officially `+` might only be used in the query string (after `?`).

This is what URLEncoder is for:

```
"?x=" + URLEncoder.encode("Hello World", "UTF-8");
"?x=" + URLEncoder.encode("ŝi estas ĉarma", "UTF-8");

?x=Hello+World
?x=%C5%9Di+estas+%C4%89arma
```

The more universal class URI, obeys the specification for spaces to be replaced, using %.

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "www.streetinsider.com",
    "/Press Releases/National Trends Reflected in Plano Housing Market/9778767.html",
    "?x=ŝi estas ĉarma");
String u = uri.toString();

http://www.streetinsider.com/Press%20Releases/National%20Trends%20
Reflected%20in%20Plano%20Housing%20Market/9778767.html#?x=ŝi%20estas%20ĉarma
```

One sometime encounters URI as generalisation for File and others, and then has to be careful not introducing %20 in file names.

So probably there is a partial remapping on streetinsider of `+` or even `%20` as it seems; in order to reach the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
Both + and %20 represent spaces.
```

is not exactly true in all cases.

Space characters may only be encoded as "+" in one context: application/x-www-form-urlencoded key-value pairs.

The RFC-1866 (HTML 2.0 specification), paragraph 8.2.1. subparagraph 1. says: "The form field names and values are escaped: space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped").

Here is an example of such a string in URL where RFC-1866 allows encoding spaces as pluses: "http://example.com/over/there?name=foo+bar". So, only after "?", spaces can be replaced by pluses (in other cases, spaces should be encoded to %20). This way of encoding form data is also given in later HTML specifications, for example, look for relevant paragraphs about application/x-www-form-urlencoded in HTML 4.01 Specification, and so on.

The URL that you have provided is not a form data containing key/value pairs, it's just a path to a 9778767.html file:

```
http://www.streetinsider.com/Press%20Releases/National+Trends+Reflected+in+Plano+Housing+Market/9778767.html
```

So, it is illegal to use pluses here. The correct URL in this case should have been the following:

```
http://www.streetinsider.com/Press%20Releases/National%20Trends%20Reflected%20in%20Plano%20Housing%20Market/9778767.html
```